# PHP looping bindParam is returning false

Tags: php, pdo

I have  a search page where I build a dynamic SQL string using a couple arrays:

```php
$conditions = [];
$parameters = [];

//example - these conditions and parameters will vary
$conditions[] = "training_id = ?";
$parameters[] = $tid; 
$conditions[] = "class_date BETWEEN ? AND ?";
$parameters[] = $sd;
$parameters[] = $ed;
```

I fill the arrays based on search criteria then I build a WHERE out of the values like:

```php
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) from viewSingleTraining";
if($conditions)
{
    $sql .= " WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $conditions);
}
```

This builds a nice and clean SQL string.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from viewSingleTraining WHERE employee_id = ? AND training_id = ?
```

I prepare and bind parameters

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

foreach($parameters as $key => $val)
{
    debug_to_console('key and value ' . $key + 1 . ' ' . $val);
    $stmt->bindParam($key + 1, $val);
}

$stmt->execute();
```

debug_to_console shows the correct expected values but I fail on the bindParam function during the attempt at foreach loop.

I get the generic "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindParam() on boolean" error which I know means bindParam returned false, but I do not see why.

Comment: this error message is related to prepare(), not bindParam

Comment: That said, there is no point in using bindParam(). [Just send your parameters into execute()](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/dynamical_where)

Comment: Thank you. So if I send the parameters into execute they need to be comma separated right?

Comment: they need to be **an array**. just what execute() accepts.

Comment: That worked. Thank you. I will read more about it,